# Vagrant / Debian / Puppet / Elasticsearch init.d start-stop-daemon won't start the service

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, debian, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to setup a local cluster of Debian boxes running ElasticSearch provided by Puppet on Vagrant.

I am using the official puppet module. The init script is available here http://goo.gl/Z3q1NI.

Provisioning runs without any issue but ES is not up.

When i run :

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

The ES server does not start

I modified the script around the start command to try and find the reason why :

```
    echo $PATH
    start-stop-daemon --start -b --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo start-stop-daemon --start -b --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
```

This end up echoing :

```
root@es:~# /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
[....] Starting Elasticsearch Server:
/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start -b --user elasticsearch -c elasticsearch --pidfile /var/run/elasticsearch.pid --exec /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -- -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
. ok
```

When I copy the full command line in the shell, the service starts as intended.

The PATH looks OK and the command is apparently rendered properly inside the script.

I found similar issues around this but solutions involve initial problems with PATH or variables used in the script which both look alright in this case.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the vagrant user to start a service? Might be worth `su` ing to the vagrant user and then launch the command.

Answer (score 0):

The ES_HEAP_SIZE was set too high, more than what I allocate this vagrant box. I saw that by removing the -b flag in the command.

Not sure exactly why it wasn't breaking when ran directly in the shell (running as root in both cases), it might have something to do with `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (elasticsearch silently not starting without any logs), and it was wrong permissions not on the config files, but on the directory containing it.